# How to Perform Redirect From Static Resources?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a special requirement to redirect static resources in ASP.NET Webform. So for example if there is a static file at location http://testdomain.com/files/abc.pdf, Now whenever this url is entered it must redirect to http://testdomain.com/abc.aspx or simply http://testdomain.com. Is this Possible. if yes how can i achieve this.

http://testdomain.com/files/abc.pdf  ========Redirects to =======>>  http://testdomain.com

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

IIS rewrite module is your answer. It’s the best way to handle this. You’ll find lots of articles on it so no point rewriting it here.. but, check out this article, pretty similar to what you are looking for - https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/nov/13/serving-urls-with-file-extensions-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application?Page=2